# 4x4 matrix reset scaling?

Tags: c++, opengl

Using C++/OpenGL.

As an example, zooming camera at cursor position:

```
Vector3 target = GetScreenToWorldPosition(in_position);

Matrix4 s(MATRIX4_IDENTITY);
s.SetScale(0.12648); /// Arbitrary value for simplicity sake.

Matrix4 t(MATRIX4_IDENTITY);
t.SetTranslation(target);

Matrix4 tMinus(MATRIX4_IDENTITY);
tMinus.SetTranslation(-target);

Camera *camera = GetCurrentCamera();
Matrix4 matrix = camera->GetWorldMatrix();
matrix *= t * s * tMinus;

l_camera->SetScale(1, 1, 1);
l_camera->SetTranslation(?);
l_camera->SetRotation(?);
```

Is there a way to reset the scale while keeping the absolute translation/rotation?

```
Matrix4:
float m[16];

Row-Major:
m[00], m[01], m[02], m[03]
m[04], m[05], m[06], m[07]
m[08], m[09], m[10], m[11]
m[12], m[13], m[14], m[15]

m[00], m[04], m[08] = Cross vector
m[01], m[05], m[09] = Up vector
m[02], m[06], m[10] = Normal vector
m[12], m[13], m[14] = Translation vector
```

Based on [rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76) suggestion:

```
Vector3 l_scale;

l_scale.x = sqrt(m[0] * m[0] + m[4] * m[4] + m[8] * m[8]);
l_scale.y = sqrt(m[1] * m[1] + m[5] * m[5] + m[9] * m[9]);
l_scale.z = sqrt(m[2] * m[2] + m[6] * m[6] + m[10] * m[10]);

m[0] /= l_scale.x;
m[4] /= l_scale.y;
m[8] /= l_scale.z;

m[1] /= l_scale.x;
m[5] /= l_scale.y;
m[9] /= l_scale.z;

m[2] /= l_scale.x;
m[6] /= l_scale.y;
m[10] /= l_scale.z;
```

It looks promising but so far, what used to be zooming in is now zooming out and vise-versa. Plus, there is some wobbling effects which indicates that something is not quite right.

Comment: Which data type is `Matrix4`?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Like I've mentioned above. The transformations are not quite the same after resetting the scale. See anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Why dou you scale the translation? I didn't do that in my answer.

Comment: Because I do not care about the matrix as being the final result but only its components, translation, rotation and scale. Basically, we should be able to create another matrix from these components with the scale being 1,1,1 and have the same world translation and rotation.

Comment: Think of the matrix as being the transformations of a cube in a 3D space. Resetting the scale should not move the cube at all.

Comment: *"Resetting the scale should not move the cube at all."* Yes I know. The `m[12] /= l_scale.x;` `m[13] /= l_scale.y;`, `m[14] /= l_scale.z;` is wrong. Remove it and it will work.The fields 12-14 contains the absolute translation If you change it, the cube "moves".

Comment: You are right. I thought the translation would have been altered by the scaling. Base on this fact, I think the original question is a bit different now. How do we apply the matrix scale to the translation? Would this be accurate? t = l_matrix.GetTranslation() * l_matrix.GetScale()

Comment: Keep in mind that what is important here is to be able to create another matrix with the scaled matrix transforms:
l_camera->SetScale(1, 1, 1);
l_camera->SetTranslation(?);
l_camera->SetRotation(?);

Comment: I don't understand. The question is answered. You cannot change the question. If you have a new question then [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Anyway, if you want to scale the translation, you have to: `t = l_matrix.GetScale() * l_matrix.GetTranslation()`. The matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: If you have 2 scale matrices and a translation: `t = scale2 * translate * scale1`, then `translate` is scaled by `scale2` but not by `scale1`. Hence, you cannot "reset" the translation scaling, as this information will be lost. The matrix does not save the history of its creation.

Comment: Very well. The question is answered but my problem remains. I'll make another question as you suggested. I guess the confusion comes from that l_camera->SetTranslation(?) takes a vector3 not a matrix. I’m still digging and thank you for your contribution.

Comment: `l_camera->SetTranslation(?)` takes an [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) and sets the fields from 12 to 14.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing the matrix, you can calculate the scale for each axis. In the following `cm` is the matrix:

```cpp
float scaleX = sqrt(cm[0][0]*cm[0][0] + cm[0][1]*cm[0][1] + cm[0][2]*cm[0][2]);
float scaleY = sqrt(cm[1][0]*cm[1][0] + cm[1][1]*cm[1][1] + cm[1][2]*cm[1][2]);
float scaleZ = sqrt(cm[2][0]*cm[2][0] + cm[2][1]*cm[2][1] + cm[2][2]*cm[2][2]);
```

If you want to "reset" the scale while keeping the absolute translation and rotation, you need to normalize the axis. The length of a normalized vector ([Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)) is 1:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    cm[0][i] /= scaleX;
    cm[1][i] /= scaleY;
    cm[2][i] /= scaleZ;
}
```

If the scale for the 3-axes is identical, the result for `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `scaleZ` will also be identically. Hence, you can tweak the code and only calculate one scale.

---

Don't change the translation of the matrix. The fields 12-14 contains the absolute translation. If you change it, the cube "moves".

The matrix multiplication is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). If you have 2 scale matrices and a translation matrix and multiply them in the following order:

```
m = scale2 * translate * scale1
```

Then `translate` is scaled with `scale2`, but not with `scale1`. Hence, you cannot *reset* the translation scaling, as this information will be lost. The matrix does not save the history of its creation.

Comment: `translate` would be scaled with `scale1` but not with `scale2` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the transformation as 3 vectors/matrices for translation, rotation and scale and create a matrix from them when needed:

```cpp
void CreateMatrix(Matrix4 translation, Matrix4 rotation, Matrix4 scale, Matrix4& out) {
    out = scale * rotation * translation;
}

void Translate(Matrix4 translate, Matrix4& translation, Matrix4& rotation, Matrix4& scale) {
    translation *= translate;
}

void Rotate(Matrix4 rotate, Matrix4& translation, Matrix4& rotation, Matrix4& scale) {
    translation *= rotate;
    scale *= rotate;
    rotation *= rotate;
}

void Scale(Matrix4 scaling, Matrix4& translation, Matrix4& rotation, Matrix4& scale) {
    translation *= scaling;
    scale *= scaling;
}
```

To reset the scale, set the scale matrix to identity / the scale vector to zero.